# Get values from subcollection 'sem' with reference to 'academic year' && "COURSE NAME"

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in Firestore database.I need to get values from subcollection 'sem' with reference to 'academic year' && "COURSE NAME".attached photo below

[image]

[image]

I need queries for getting that sem value can any one help me

Comment: When you say "with reference to 'academic year' and 'course name'" do you mean you have those values already and you want query for the subcollection on the document which has those specific values? Also, there are 4 documents in that subcollection. Do you want to retrieve all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getSem(String academic, String course) async { 

     semNameList.clear();
    temSemEditList.clear();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("course")
        .where('academic_year', isEqualTo: academic)
        .where('course_name', isEqualTo: course)
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      for(var doc in val.docs){
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("course")
            .doc(doc.id)
            .collection("sem")
        .orderBy('sem_name')
            .get()
            .then((value){
          for (var doc in value.docs) {
            SemModel semModel = SemModel(
              documentId: doc.id,
              semName: doc["sem_name"],
              startDate: doc["start_date"],
              endDate: doc["end_date"],
            );
            temSemEditList.add(semModel);
            semNameList.add(semModel.semName);
          }
          update();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve all of the documents in the "sem" subcollection on the document which has a specific value for academic_year and course_name, you'll first need to query for the course document, and then get all documents in the "sem subcollection":

```dart
final coursesRef = db.collection("course");
final academicYear = "2015 - 2017";
final courseName = "B.sc Computer Science";

coursesRef
  .where("academic_year", isEqualTo: academicYear)
  .where("course_name", isEqualTo: courseName)
  .limit(1) // Limit to 1 document
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) =>
    snapshot.docs.elementAt(0).reference.collection("sem").get()) // Get the sem subcollection
  .then((querySnapshot) {
    // Do something with the sem subcollection
    for (var docSnap in querySnapshot.docs) {
      print('${docSnap.id} => ${docSnap.data()}');
    }
  });
```